# Next JS serverless deployment on AWS ECS/Fargate: environment variable issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

so my goal is to deploy a serverless Dockerized NextJS application on ECS/Fargate.
So when I docker build my project using the command `docker build . -f development.Dockerfile --no-cache -t myapp:latest` everything is running successfully except Docker build doesn't consider the env file in my project's root directory. Once build finishes, I push the Docker image to Elastic Container Repository(ECR) and my Elastic Container Service(ECS) references that ECR.

So naturally, my built image doesn't have a ENV file(contains the API keys and DB credentials), and as a result my app is deployed but all of the services relying on those credentials are failing because there isn't an ENV file in my container and all of the variables become undefined or null.

To fix this issue I looked at this [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html) and implemented a solution that stores my .env file in AWS S3 and that S3 ARN gets refrenced in the container service where the .env file is stored. However, that didn't workout and I think it's because of the way I'm setting my
`next.config.js` to reference my environmental files in my local codebase. I also tried to set my environmental variables manually(very unsecure, screenshot below) when configuring the container in my task defination, and that didn't work either.

My `next.confg.js`

```js
const dotEnvConfig = { path: `../../${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env` };

require("dotenv").config(dotEnvConfig);

module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    xyzKey: process.env.xyzSecretKey || "",
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    appUrl: process.env.app_url || "",
  },
};
```

So on my local codebase in the root directory I have two files `development.env` (local api keys) and `production.env`(live api keys) and my next.config.js is located in `/packages/app/next.config.js`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently it was just a plain NextJS's way of handling env variables.

In `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    user: process.env.SQL_USER || "",
// add all the env var here
  },

};
```

and to call the environmental variable `user` in the app all you have to do is call `process.env.user` and `user` will reference `process.env.SQL_USER` in my local `.env` file where it will be stored as `SQL_USER="abc_user"`

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting the environment variables in the ECS task definition. In order to prevent storing sensitive values in the task definition you should use AWS Parameter Store, or AWS Secrets Manager, as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html).

Comment: Hey Mark, so I have tried it with AWS parameter store and secret manager before, but the point is that the environment variables are not being read by NextJS. I think it's the way I'm setting an explicit path to my root directory in the dot-env-config because when Docker injects the variable in the container from any service I choose(Secret manager, Param store, or S3 ARN) I'm not sure if those "injected" variables are in the path that I'm setting in NextJS DotEnvConfig.

Comment: Environment variables in ECS aren't in any path. They aren't stored in a file anywhere, they are in-memory in the Docker runtime environment. Just like when you run `export MY_VAR=test` and then `echo $MY_VAR` that is an environment variable that was never stored in a file anywhere. Maybe you should remove the `dotEnvConfig ` or only use it for local development.

Comment: Ok let me try that actually, and I'll give you an update once it works. thanks

Comment: Hey Mark, so apparently it was just a weird Next JS bug. So instead of setting up serverRuntimeConfig and publicRunTimeConfig, I just removed that and setup env: { xyz: "my-key" } and in the main app called it for example process.env.xyz

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Rohan could you please post a code snippet of that. I tried what you wrote but didn't manage it get it to work.